# Mixing AspectJ and Scala in an Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, aspectj

Any one been able to get a Scala and AspectJ (AJDT) to play nicely together in Eclipse 3.6?

It seems Scala's weaver conflicts with AspectJ's weaver. 
I'm hoping I'm just missing something.

*Edit: Play nicely in the same project*

Comment: Matt R below is correct, it is possible to install the two plugins together, but there may be some incompatibilities that we are not aware of.  So, please be more specific as to what is going on.\

Comment: @Andrew Eisenberg Basically the AspectJ weavers stops weaving once I add the Scala Builder to the project. If I disable the scala builder all works fine except no Scala compilation.

Comment: Right...I see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment above, it looks like you want a single project to use both the AspectJ builder and the Scala builder.  This is not possible.  Each one delegates to its own compiler and the two compilers are not (yet) compatible.  The Scala compiler can build Java and Scala code together, and the AspectJ compiler can build AspectJ and Java code together, but that's it.

If you want aspects to apply to your Scala code, you must separate your AspectJ and Scala code into different projects and then add the Scala project to the inpath of your AspectJ project.

This is the same thing that you would need to do if you were compiling from ant or the command line.

Comment: This is infact what I did. AspectJ + Java is extremely powerful (I would even argue more powerful than Scala). But Scala wins syntactically. If only Java 7 was out and with closures :)

Comment: If you are using annotation-based aspects, it's perfectly possible to write them in Scala within a Scala project then compile them with scalac & iajc. So there are projects that compile properly with Ant but not in Scala IDE. I hope the ScalaBuilder is extended to weave annotated Scala aspects.

Comment: Further to my last comment - you can run annotated Scala aspects within the IDE using load-time weaving (http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#enabling-load-time-weaving).

Answer (score 2):

Right now, the recommended version is [still Eclipse3.5.2](http://www.scala-ide.org/).

Tickets like [1000075](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000075?comment=8098885#comment:8098885) or [3251](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/3251?comment=7970173#comment:7970173) mention:

> If you're desperate there's an experimental nightly build update site at http://download.scala-ide.org/nightly-update-wip-helios-2.8.0.final.

Today, the current nightly you could try with Helios 3.6 would be:

http://download.scala-ide.org/nightly-update-master-2.8.1.final

Comment: The version I tried a while ago was the nightly but I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for some time now. Here is my Solution:

First, separate your Scala and your AspectJ code into different projects.

Then add an Ant builder to your Scala project. It runs whenever the scala builder runs and does the weaving. It uses ant4eclipse to extract the classpath, but you'll have to supply the location of the scala library.

Build.xml:

```
<project name="simple-example" default="compile"
xmlns:ant4eclipse="antlib:org.ant4eclipse"
         xmlns:antcontrib="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">

<ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary name="org.scala-ide.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER">
  <fileset file="../lib/scala-library.jar"/>
</ant4eclipse:jdtClassPathLibrary >

<ant4eclipse:getJdtClassPath 
    workspacedirectory=".."
    projectName="lpfExample"
    property="classpath"/>

<target name="compile">
    <iajc sourceroots="src" destdir="bin">
        <inpath>
            <pathelement location="bin" />
        </inpath>
        <aspectpath>
            <pathelement location="../aspects/bin"/>
        </aspectpath>
        <classpath path="${classpath}"/>
    </iajc>
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean having both the Scala plug-in and AJDT installed simultaneously? This is definitely doable -- it's needed for developing the Scala plug-in itself, for example.

I do the following:

- Install the AspectJ dev tools + eclipse weaving service feature
- Install Scala IDE, but omit JDT Weaving for Scala

Comment: No I have both plugins installed. The problem is that I would like to use AspectJ for cross cutting around advice that I can't do with Traits.